# Is there no support for DataGrid control in XAML in C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++-winrt

I created a Blank Universal Windows application in VS 2017 v 15.7.4 but I don't see a DataGrid control in the list of XAML controls. Is there no way to deal with collections of data as a data source providing the functionality offered by DataGrid?

Regards,
Juan Dent

Answer (score 0):

There is no DataGrid in the WinRT (i.e. UWP) flavor of [XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls). This is nothing particular about the C++/WinRT, as you'd encounter the same restriction if you were authoring a UWP app in C# or C++/CX.

Comment: But RicardoPons has given a link to a DataGrid that supports UWP Applications (although it requires Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform and thus cannot be currently used in native C++ therefore not in C++/WinRT)...

Answer (score 0):

There is a DataGrid support now for UWP Applications you can find the new control in the UWP Toolkit 
Please read this article for more details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/datagrid

This is the nuget package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/

Comment: This DataGrid cannot be installed in a native C++/WinRT app, though. I think its missing the metadata so it can generate the C++ sources...

Comment: I found this info about the toolkit .

Comment: Windows Community Toolkit is available as a Visual Studio NuGet package for new or existing C# and VB.NET projects.